# Add a decorative area around a node, that behaves like an Effect

Tags: javafx-8

For a card game, I'm currently writing, I created a custom "control" that represents a card. It can be flipped, dragged around, selected, and will be scaled, translated and so forth during the course of the game.

One core feature of a card is that is can be "highlighted" in different ways. The most basic form of highlighting is showing a glowing border (animated) around the card.

I started with JavaFX effects here (DropShadow with animated spread/radius) but quickly turned away from this, because performance turned out to be very bad.

So, I replaced the effect with an animated ImageView "behind" the card (basic sprite animation from sprite sheet with a pre-rendered glow animation). This solves the performance issue, but introduced numerous other problems I'm currently trying to tackle...

Since, I don't want the "anchor point" to be the top-left corner of the glow around the card but the top-left corner of the card itself, I tried to offset the ImageView within the card node by -X/-Y.

(Different highlights can "expand" the node by different amounts, this should not affect the location of the node, and when setting the location of the node you should not have to care about potentially differing highlight offsets or highlights at all.)

At first this looked good, but this still affects the bounds of the whole node. For instance, if I add a mouse event listener to the node, it fires when clicking in the "glow" area, even though I set the ImageView to mouse transparent. I would have to create "proxy" methods for all event methods on the custom node and forward them to the "inner" card node. Which is of course possible - but frankly not the solution I hope to find.

The current card node has basically the following structure:

```
   public class Card extends Pane {

        // the view that will contain the border glow (blue area in image below)
        private ImageView effectView;

        // stand-in for the rest of the card stuff (image etc)
        private Rectangle placeholderForCardContent;

        public Card() {
            effectView = new ImageView();
            effectView.setMouseTransparent(true);

            placeholderForCardContent = new Rectangle();

            getChildren().addAll(effectView, placeholderForCardContent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            // offsets are defined by the current highlight
            effectView.setLayoutX(-50); 
            effectView.setLayoutY(-50);
            effectView.setFitWidth(getWidth() + 100);
            effectView.setFitHeight(getHeight() + 100);

            placeholderForCardContent.setLayoutX(0);
            placeholderForCardContent.setLayoutY(0);
            placeholderForCardContent.setWidth(getWidth());
            placeholderForCardContent.setHeight(getHeight());
        }
    }
```

Example: new Card().setOnMouseClick() and the like should only affect the area currently equal to placeHolderForCardContent, but not extend to effectView. Simply, it should behave like an Effect of the node...

The following image shows was I try to build:

[image]

How is something like this properly done in JavaFX?
Can it be properly done?

Answer (score 0):

`setMouseTransparent(true)` works properly for the `effectView`.

However, the parent's bounds (`Pane`) still include the `effectView` and generate the mouse event. And since `pickOnBounds` for `Regions` is set to `true` by default (which is the thing I missed, since the general default, according to java doc, is `false`) we need to set it to `false`.

Then it works.